# Mule FTP transfer problems

Tags: ftp, copy, mule

I've got a problem with transfering files with Mule trough FTP.
The mule console says Failed to retrieve file 40525600_100492.xml. Ftp error: 550
but all files but one is transfered but when they end up in the other FTP they
are renamed to a 0aa00a0-00aaa0-00akahd-sakka-aaa.dat-file.

What is wrong? Do I need to have a delay?

```
<flow name="XR-importFlow2" doc:name="XR-importFlow2">
    <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="XX.XX.XX.77" port="21" path="XRRDF/wrkcd" user="user" password="password" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" disableTransportTransformer="true" passive="true"/>
    <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="xx.xx.xx.xx" port="21" path="x-path" user="anonymous" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overwrite the default name mule is using for copying files, specify the `outputPattern` attribute in `ftp:outbound-endpoint`. To copy files with original name, you can use `outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]"`, like this:

```
<ftp:outbound-endpoint host="xx.xx.xx.xx" port="21" path="x-path" user="anonymous" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]"/>
```

Try specifying a `pollingFrequency` attribute on `ftp:inbound-endpoint` with a value of may be `60000` (1min), to see if it helps you